# The sum of $\frac{2}{(n-1)(n-2)(n)} $ converges to what number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

$$ \sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{2}{(n-1)(n-2)(n)} $$ is a telescoping series but how can I make it more visual? How can I write that in telescoping form? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n - a_{n+1})$$

---

I already have then in partial fractions,

$$ \sum_{n=4}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n-2} -\frac{2}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n} \right) $$

We can re-write,
$$\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n-1}\right)$$

and split in two telescoping-series:

$$ \sum_{n=4}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n-2} +\frac{1}{n-1} \right) -  \sum_{n=4}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}\right) $$

so the formula for the partial sum will be:

$$S_n = \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}\right)$$

and the lim of $S_n$ will give us the convergence:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = \frac{1}{6}$$

I would like to thank everyone who responded my question

Comment: suggest you include details as to how it telescopes. [It would "show your work" and make it less likely the question gets closed]

Comment: "Telescoping" is not as narrow as your last line ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n - a_{n+1})$) suggests. Put your terms in a more natural order: $\frac{2}{n-2}-\frac{4}{n-1}+\frac{2}{n}$. Then write out (the long way) the first 3 or 4 partial sums:  $\left(\frac{2}{2}-\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{4}{4}+\frac{2}{5}\right)+\cdots$ It's "telescoping" because once you do this you will see how all but finitely many of these terms cancel.

Comment: Hint. Look to the partial fractions that you have found and  split the series in two: $\sum_{n=4}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{n-2} -\frac{2}{n-1} \right)$ and $\sum_{n=4}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{n} -\frac{2}{n-1} \right)$

Comment: @RobertZ thanks, that was really helpful, in the second term i can make like $-\sum_{n=4}^\infty \left( \frac{2}{n-1}-\frac{2}{n}\right)$ right

Comment: @jonataniaczinski Good point!

Comment: @Sil you'r right, the cte are wrong, im editing right now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the value the series converges to, manipulate the terms as follows:
$$\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n-1}=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n-2}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$

It should converge to $1/6$.

Allow me to revise:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=4}^N\left(\frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{2}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}\right)
&=\sum_{n=4}^N\frac{1}{n-2}-2\sum_{n=4}^N\frac{1}{n-1}+\sum_{n=4}^N\frac{1}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{N-2}\frac{1}{n}-2\sum_{n=3}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=4}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\sum_{n=4}^{N-2}\frac{1}{n}\right)-\left(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{N-1}+2\sum_{n=4}^{N-2}\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{N-1}+\sum_{n=4}^{N-2}\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{N-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{N-1}
\end{align}
As $N\to\infty$, it is now clear that the sum converges to $1/6$.

Comment: Ummmm.... $1/6$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork ummm...?

Comment: What you wrote is divergent.